# ByteBuffer.wrap() in glTexImage2D causing excessive garbage collection

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, garbage-collection, android-camera

I am currently making the following openGL calls onDrawFrame() in an android GLSurfaceView():

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, cameraTexture[0]);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, camPreviewSize.width, camPreviewSize.height, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,     GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(yArray));
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

I need to do this (or something like it) every frame because I am processing a live feed from an android camera preview with a custom callback method using android's `setPreviewCallback()` functionality within the camera, but my garbage collection is going absolutely wild (the following repeats about 10x a second!):

```
....

GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 18ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 22ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 25ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 20ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 20ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 16ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1530K, 42% free 3671K/6307K, paused 22ms

....
```

`yArray` is a byte array, and I wrap it to a buffer. I've done profiling using DDMS, and indeed the majority of allocations are byte arrays, and from the reading I have done on the wrap function, it seems as though it may create an underlying byte[] on a call to wrap, which will then be collected by the GC after it is used as a texture.

**How can I reduce the number of allocations?** Should I change by GL calls somehow? It seems like I could just be reusing the same byte array instead, but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be so appreciated! This amount of garbage scares me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [well documented android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2794) relating to the `setPreviewCallback()` method that causes excessive garbage collection. The solution to this problem is to use the newer method `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer` where you preallocate a buffer that is added and re-added on every fram with the `addCallbackBuffer` method:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
...
  mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(callbackBuffer);
  mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(class that implements PreviewCallback);
...
}
```

and in the onPreviewFrame function the buffer must be added again:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] yuvArray, Camera camera) {
...
  camera.addCallbackBuffer(callbackBuffer);
...
}
```

to address the initial suspicion that `ByteBuffer.wrap()` is allocating memory in the GL calls: it is not. It will actually use the underlying array (`yArray` in the provided code) and will not allocate new memory to be garbage collected.

Comment: Glad you found the answer. All the same, you may want to try using glTexSubImage2D instead of glTexImage2D if you're just refreshing the same size/type texture every frame, it may offer better performance. See here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Updating_A_Texture

Comment: Great! Got it working using glTexSubImage2D. I didn't realize that this was the true intended usage for glTexSubImage2D–thank you for enlightening me. I am not sure it is making anything faster, but I'd like to avoid as many common errors as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `ByteBuffer` instance on every `onDrawFrame` call, which is immediately garbage and collected. You'd need this only when the size of the data changed, and thus the texture size dimensions itself. I don't think this's likely.

Preallocate the `ByteBuffer` one time and update its content via bulk methods.

Comment: I tried this and was getting buffer overflow errors. I was using the .put method using the arrays is input on the put method. I will try again, try to figure those out, and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSmith Make sure you set the buffer.position(0) before you refill the array (otherwise it will append to the end).

Comment: That was indeed the problem with the buffer, but as you can see from the answer I provided above, it was not actually the cause for concern.